# Magento 2.3.3 - additional_options on Product being Returned as "null" when Using Stripe or Paypal

Tags: magento2, checkout, module

I'll expand a little more on the title. I have an in-house Magento 2 module that connects to our local gift card service to facilitate the use of in-store gift cards on Magento, in addition to in-store. The product page has multiple inputs and they vary depending on gift card type (virtual or physical). The inputs are transferred to the quote item, which are sent to the order item through a cart plugin. This part works when I use built in Magento payment methods and Authorize.net. Tested on Direct Post, the additional Auth.net module from Magento and using Authorize.net's Magento 2 module. However, when I use Stripe and Paypal, the array that holds the options returns a null and I get an undefined_index for 'additional_options.' One thing to note is that I did not write this originally and am maintaining it.

Observer where it fails on invoice payment;

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $amount = 0;
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        $invoiceItems = $invoice->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($invoiceItems as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getProductType() == 'localgc') {
                $options = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductOptions();
                $additionalOptions = $options['additional_options'];
                foreach ($additionalOptions as $option) {
                    if ($option['label'] == 'amount') {
                        $amount = $option['value'];
                    }
                    if ($option['label'] == 'email') {
                        $gcRecipEmail = $option['value'];
                    }
                    if ($option['label'] == 'type') {
                        $gcType = $option['value'];
                    }
                    if ($option['label'] == 'recip_name') {
                        $gcRecipName = $option['value'];
                    }
                    if ($option['label'] == 'gc_giftmessage') {
                        $gcGiftMessage = $option['value'];
                    }
                }
                if ($amount != 0 && isset($gcType) && $gcType == 'virtual') {
                    $newCardNumber = $this->gcHelper->getNextCardNum();
                    $options = array(
                        'x_Card_Num'    => urlencode($newCardNumber),
                        'x_Type'        => urlencode('SL'),
                        'x_Invoice_Num' => urlencode($invoice->getOrder()->getIncrementId()),
                        'x_Amount'      => urlencode($amount)
                    );
                    $success = $this->gcHelper->postGCLinkTransaction($options);
                    if ($success[0] != 1) {
                        throw new LocalizedException(__('Gift card purchase failed.'));
                    } else {
                        $gcRecipName = isset($gcRecipName) ? $gcRecipName : 'Gift Card Recipient';
                        $gcGiftMessage = isset($gcGiftMessage) ? $gcGiftMessage : 'Enjoy your gift!';
                        $this->gcHelper->sendActivatedEmail($amount, $newCardNumber, $gcRecipEmail, $gcRecipName, $gcGiftMessage, $invoice->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail());
                        $additionalOptions[] = array('label' => 'posimgc_num', 'value' => $newCardNumber);
                        $options['additional_options'] = $additionalOptions;
                        $item->getOrderItem()->setProductOptions($options);
                        $orderItem = $item->getOrderItem();
                        $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
                        $orderItemExtension = $extensionAttributes
                            ? $extensionAttributes
                            : $this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
                        $orderItemExtension->setGiftcardInformation($additionalOptions);
                        $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
                        $item->setGiftcardInformation($additionalOptions);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('Gift Card purchased amount was null...'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where the primary failure is taking place. When I use Stripe or Paypal, `$additionalOptions` ends up as null so I get `undefined index additional_options`. I added test logging and `$options` will return the right array but when it gets passed to the new variable to identify where to look, it fails out.

This is what I get for `$options`:

```
{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9tYWdlMjMucG9zaW1ob3N0aW5nLmNvbS9nY2xpbmstY2FyZC5odG1s","product":"879","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","item":"879","giftcard_amount":"50.000000","gctype":"virtual","gc_recipient_email":"myemailaddress","gc_recipient_name":"test","gc_gift_message":"dfsdgf","qty":"1"}}
```

And the plugin code that moves the options from quote items to order items;

```
    public function aroundConvert(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject, callable $proceed, $quoteItem, $data)
    {
        $orderItem = $proceed($quoteItem, $data);
        if ($orderItem->getProductType() == Giftcard::TYPE_GIFTCARD) {

            if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options') instanceof Countable) {
                if ($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options') instanceof Countable) {
                    $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                } else {
                    $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                }
                if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
                    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    $options['additional_options'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                }
            }
        }

        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on why I would be returned a null when I use Stripe or Paypal but it works on other methods. Am I missing an array_merge somewhere or is it something else? The setup works properly if not using Stripe or Paypal.

Comment: I also have this problem with Paypal, do you remember the fix for this